# pip installing data files to the wrong place

Tags: python, pip, packaging, easy-install, package-managers

The source for the package is [here](https://github.com/captn3m0/hackertray/)

I'm installing the package from the index via:

```
easy_install hackertray
pip install hackertray
```

`easy_install` installs `images/hacker-tray.png` to the following folder:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hackertray-1.8-py2.7.egg/images/
```

While, `pip` installs it to:

```
/usr/local/images/
```

My setup.py is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='hackertray',
      version='1.8',
      description='Hacker News app that sits in your System Tray',
      packages=['hackertray'],
      data_files=[('images', ['images/hacker-tray.png'])])
```

My `MANIFEST` file is:

```
include images/hacker-tray.png
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't use `data_files` with relative paths. Actually, don't use `data_files` at all, unless you make sure the target paths are absolute ones properly generated in a cross-platform way insted of hard coded values.

Use `package_data` instead:

```
setup(
    # (...)
    package_data={
        "hackertray.data": [
            "hacker-tray.png",
        ],
    },
)
```

where `hackertray.data` is a proper python package (i.e. is a directory that contains a file named `__init__.py`) and `hacker-tray.png` is right next to  `__init__.py`.

Here's how it should look:

```
.
|-- hackertray
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- data
|       |-- __init__.py
|       `-- hacker-tray.png
`-- setup.py
```

You can get the full path to the image file using:

```
from pkg_resources import resource_filename
print os.path.abspath(resource_filename('hackertray.data', 'hacker-tray.png'))
```

I hope that helps.

PS: Python<2.7 seems to have a bug regarding packaging of the files listed in `package_data`. Always make sure to have a manifest file if you're using something older than Python 2.7 for packaging. See here for more info: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/python-virtualenv/v5KJ78LP9Mo/OiBqMcYVFYAJ

Comment: A few clarifications: 

1) What do you mean when you say `hackertray.data` is a _proper python package_? Do I need to create another package just for the data, or is it still part of the original package.

2)I did what you said and the resulting distribution still does not put the image file in its proper place. I've uploaded the package [here](http://ge.tt/66oOe871/v/0).

Comment: For your specific case: `cd hackertray-1.9;
mkdir hackertray/data;
touch hackertray/data/__init__.py;
mv hackertray/hacker-tray.png hackertray/data;` and add `hackertray.data` to `packages` list in setup.py

Comment: Also, i'd just use `find_packages()` instead of manually writing a package list. `from setuptools import find_packages` and pass `packages=find_packages()` to `setup`.