# Django's locale files installed in weird place

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm creating a new environment setup script for my organization, but am having problems with installing Django. After executing `pip install Django==1.4.19` under virtualenv a test that requires localization support yields:

```
  ...
  File "/home/ubuntu/venvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 105, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 194, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venvs/meynv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 184, in translation
    current_translation = _fetch(language, fallback=default_translation)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 147, in _fetch
    res._info = res._info.copy()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_info'
```

Diving into Django's `trans_real.translation()` function reveals that the error comes from trying to find catalog `django` under `~/venvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/locale`, however that directory contains no translation files or `LC_MESSAGES` directory:

```
(myenv)ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls ~/venvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/locale/en/
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1637 Jun 22 13:51 formats.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1094 Jun 22 13:51 formats.pyc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Jun 22 13:51 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  149 Jun 22 13:51 __init__.py
```

Instead, the .po and .mo files can be found under the virtualenv's root:

```
(myenv)ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l ~/venvs/myenv/django/conf/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   356 Jun 22 13:51 django.mo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 21041 Jun 22 13:51 django.po
```

In general the directory `~/venvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django` contains no .po- or .mo-files, and all of them can be found under `~/venvs/myenv/django` in appropriate subdirectories.

Pip version is 7.0.3, and if I downgrade it to version 6.1.1 (which we have been using earlier), the translation files can be (properly?) found under `site-packages/django` and everything works.

What could cause this pecular behaviour with newer pip?

**UPDATE**
It appears also `djcelery` package is affected by this. Its .html-files (and only those) are installed under virtualenv's root, while the rest is under `site-packages/djcelery`:

```
/home/ubuntu/venvs/myenv/djcelery/
+-- templates
    +-- admin
    |   +-- djcelery
    |       +-- change_list.html
    +-- djcelery
        +-- confirm_rate_limit.html
```

Is there some common denominator between these html-files and django's .po/.mo-files?

Comment: Do you have `LOCALE_PATHS` set in your project settings?

Comment: @marksweb thanks for the input, I do not. But I'd like to stress that the issue seems to be about pip not properly installing Django, and not as much about Django not finding the files. See also update.

Comment: I'd be keen to know how to resolve this properly: it seems to be occurring for me on my jenkins machine (running jessie/sid of some sort), but not on my Mac.

Comment: It may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/20370738/188, and the way django/djcelery package up their data files.

Comment: Got same problem here. Thank you so much for figuring out the weird place of the translations!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an elegant fix, but if you just need to get your project up and running and downgrading pip is not an option, a symlink will do it:

```
ln -s ~/.virtualenvs/<virtualenv>/django/conf/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/ \
~/.virtualenvs/<virtualenv>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/locale/en/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I was using testing with Tox old django 1.2 project, I created following function that automatically solves it:

```
import os

from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree


def resolve_pip_data_files(fix_packages=None):
    """
    :param fix_packages: list of packages to fix, defaults to Django

    """
    if fix_packages is None:
        fix_packages = ['django']

    env_path = os.environ.get('VIRTUAL_ENV', None)
    site_packages = get_python_lib()

    if not env_path:
        return  # not in virtual env

    for package in fix_packages:
        package_data_dir = os.path.join(env_path, package)
        package_dir = os.path.join(site_packages, package)

        if os.path.exists(package_data_dir) and os.path.exists(package_dir):
            copy_tree(package_data_dir, package_dir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    resolve_pip_data_files()
```