# Node server files in python pypi package

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, pip

In my python3 project, there is a node script to be run via node server. When the python program runs it runs the node script by itself.

Suppose my package directory layout is like this:

```
 /
|_package_name/
   |-__init.py
   |-project.py
   |-project.js
|-setup.py
|-README.md
```

I can add a MANIFEST file so that during packaging project.js will be added into the package but how to find the path of the that included node script after installation so that I can use that like this:

```
sp.Popen(["node","/path/to/project.js"],stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.PIPE,encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Don't use MANIFEST.in — it's only for source distribution (`python setup.py sdist`). Use `data_files` or `package_data`. See an example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20370738/7976758

Comment: Thanks,now on I will